# Loading XML string as a column from sql server database to bigquery returns error ##400 Resources exceeded during query execution

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to load a `XML` file from operational database(`SQL Server`) as a string into `BigQuery`. I'm taking the following error:

> 400 Resources exceeded during query execution: UDF out of memory.; Failed to read Parquet file /bigstore/bigquery-prod-upload-europe-north1/prod-scotty-9ab0ddc4-9166-4a2e-a6fd-fa5adb7948dd. This might happen if the file contains a row that is too large, or if the total size of the pages loaded for the queried columns is too large

How I'm supposed to handle `XML` columns while loading it to `BigQuery`? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example how to call or read the contents of the XML file?

Comment: Can you explain how is your XML and how the the table should be?

Comment: source structure example:

Comment: source structure example: id, name, creditscore1(xml),creditscore2(xml) , comments, date,, views etc , target needs to be same structure  ie., id, name, creditscore1(xml),creditscore2(xml) , comments, date,, views  with the xml column data type as string . no structural changes from the source . if you understand the error it is about exceeding row size and page size. the structure of the xml is complex hierachical structure with 100s of sub scolumn structures. Main thing is what is the limit of row size/page size in bigquery?

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts), `BigQuery` has a size limitation of 100 MB for a row size when you're using `CSV` and `JSON` files. Actually, you can have even a cell up to 100MB when you're using `CSV`.
Besides that, in nested fields the structure can't have more than 15 levels as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#limitations)